# `GLIBC_2.23' not found error

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, raspbian-jessie

I'm trying to run a Raspberry Pi build of [Tensorflow](https://github.com/samjabrahams/tensorflow-on-raspberry-pi/issues/104) and hitting the following error:

> ImportError: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.23' not found

Not too sure if this provides much info but I noticed a few similar questions asking for the results of these commands:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ jessie main ui
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ jessie main ui

apt-cache policy libc6-dev
libc6-dev:
  Installed: 2.19-18+deb8u10
  Candidate: 2.19-18+deb8u10
  Version table:
 *** 2.19-18+deb8u10 0
        500 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main armhf Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

I'm not sure how I go about getting this? If there's anything else that I can provide please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package you are running appears to have been built on Raspbian 9 Stretch, because it requires libc 2.23 (Jessie goes up to 2.19 as you've indicated).

Although the releases listed on the main page https://github.com/samjabrahams/tensorflow-on-raspberry-pi/releases are built for Jessie, the one-off binaries by Deftwork or smogili-gppdm in ticket #104 may have been built for Stretch.

You can either update your distro to Stretch or ensure you obtain a wheel file that clearly says it's for Jessie.